# Can we safely use o expansion when V expansion is not available?

Tags: expl3, expansion

For example `\exp_args:Nxo` is available but not `\exp_args:NxV`.
Can we safely use the former instead of the latter?

Comment: Usually you don't need `\exp_args` at all but generate corresponding variants of the functions you're working with. And then you can just generate V if you need V.

Comment: No, they're different even if the result might be the same. According to the guidelines a `V` argument should not be braced (but the value will be), whereas an `o` argument should be braced. The fact that `\exp_args:NxV` is not predefined is of no concern, because you can do `\exp_args_generate:n { xV }` and then you can use `\exp_args:NxV`. On the other hand, generating function variants is the recommended route.

Comment: Function `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` (+variant ...`:cn`) in `texdoc interface3` explains the syntax. `V` (and `v`) variant functions are usually enough in most cases.

Comment: For lowercase (`o`,`c`), the braces tells Tex where the set of tokens stops; for uppercase (`V`,`N`), no braces are needed because only one token is expected (usually the name of the variable).

Comment: @Cicada stronger than "no braces are needed" it is "braces should not be used" (although using braces does not always give an error for fficiency reasons. But in general you could end up with `\def{\oops}{...}` and low level tex errors if you brace N or V arguments

Comment: `\exp_args:N...` are "necessary" when `\begin` or `\group_end:` are involved and code should remain simple.

Comment: In some situations instead of hypothetical `\exp_args:NxV \macro {<x-Arg>} <V-Arg>` you can do `\exp_args:NnV \use:n { \exp_args:Nx \macro {<x-Arg>} } <V-Arg>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is not whether `o` and `V` are equivalent, which obviously is not the case, the question is whether one can emulate `V` with `o`. The answer is yes as suggested by the documentation `interface3.pdf` (p 3), but there are subtleties. The `V` arguments specifier gets the content of the variable, but things depend on the variable.

We can categorize variables

1. token list like variables : tl, str, seq, clist, prop, fp
2. int like variables: int, dim, skip, muskip
3. quark
4. intarray, fparray, cctab

For category 1 and 3, `\foo:V <variable>` is replaced by `\foo:o { <variable> }`
For category 2, `\foo:V <variable>` is replaced by `\foo:o { \<type>_use:N <variable> }`
For category 4, the variables are not suitable for a `V` argument.

### Demonstration for int, dim, skip, muskip

`\MyTest:nn` prints SUCCESS if the 2 arguments as token lists are equal, FAILURE otherwise.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \MyTest:nn {
  \tl_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { SUCCESS } { FAILURE } \\
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \MyTest:nn { Vo }

\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 1234 }
\MyTest:Vo \l_tmpa_int { \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }

\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { 1234pt }
\MyTest:Vo \l_tmpa_dim { \dim_use:N \l_tmpa_dim }

\skip_set:Nn \l_tmpa_skip { 1234pt plus 1cm minus 2mm }
\MyTest:Vo \l_tmpa_skip { \skip_use:N \l_tmpa_skip }

\muskip_set:Nn \l_tmpa_muskip { 1234mu }
\MyTest:Vo \l_tmpa_muskip { \muskip_use:N \l_tmpa_muskip }
\end{document}
```

### Demonstration for tl, str, seq, clist, prop, fp and quarks

For `\MyTest:Nn`, #1 sets `\My_var`  to `#2` and calls `\MyTest:Vo` with appropriate arguments.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \MyTest:nn {
  \tl_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { SUCCESS } { FAILURE } \\
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \MyTest:nn { Vo }
\cs_new:Nn \MyTest:Nn {
  #1 \My_var { #2 }
  \MyTest:Vo \My_var { \My_var }
}
\MyTest:Nn \tl_set:Nn { \def\My#1{#1#1} }
\MyTest:Nn \str_set:Nn { \def\My#1{#1#1} }
\MyTest:Nn \seq_set_from_clist:Nn { \def, \My, #1, {#1#1} }
\MyTest:Nn \clist_set:Nn{ \def, \My, #1, {#1#1} }
\MyTest:Nn \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn {
  \def = \My,
  #1 = {#1#1},
}
\MyTest:Nn \fp_set:Nn { 3.14159 }
\quark_new:N \q_My
\MyTest:Vo \q_My { \q_My }
\end{document}
```

### Less contrived example

This illustrate what is possible, but this should not be used in production code because it uses unsupported features.

Here we define `\foo:n` to build a property list from its argument assuming it is the raw content of a property list variable and print out the items. Then we generate 'o' and 'V' variants to finally test `\foo:o` and `\foo:V`.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \foo:n {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_prop { #1 }
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpb_prop {
    ##1$\to$##2\\
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \foo:n { o, V }
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {
  KEY1=VALUE1,
  KEY2=VALUE2,
}
\foo:V \l_tmpa_prop
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop {
  key1=value1,
  key2=value2,
}
\foo:o { \l_tmpa_prop }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

### Is it safe ?

For a short time usage, it is ok, but for deployment code it is definitely not. If LaTeX internals change, this may break in the future.

Comment: They're still not the same.

Comment: `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_prop` is absurd.

Comment: No, `o` is not equivalent to `V` even if you use `\tl_use:N`.  Try `\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ABCD }
\tl_set:No \l_tmpb_tl { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } % should assign ABCD to tmpb
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { DEFG }
\typeout{\l_tmpb_tl} % should print ABCD, but doesn't...` (and try `\exp_args:No \tl_show:n { \tl_use:N \l_My_tl }` to see why).

Comment: Argh, `\tl_use:N` is not `\the` !!!!!!!

Comment: @egreg `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_prop` is definitely weird. It is related to the question of sequences of property lists for example and has been reported https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1047

Comment: If I add `\tl_show:N \l_tmpb_prop` in the code of `\foo:n` in the “less contrived example”, when `\foo:o` is executed I get `\l_tmpb_prop=\tl_if_exist:NTF \l_tmpa_prop {\l_tmpa_prop
}{\msg_expandable_error:nnn {kernel}{bad-variable}{\l_tmpa_prop }}` which doesn't look like anything resembling a property list. And this clearly contradicts your “the answer is yes”.

Comment: My mistake: the `\tl_use:N` must not be used in that case as mentioned earlier in the answer. No contradiction.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to prove with the “demonstrations”. They all present success for obvious reasons that have nothing to do with real success: in the second one you're comparing the first level expansion of a macro with itself, so it's not at all surprising that you get “success” in all cases.

Comment: @egreg This is not completely exact. You assume that V expansion is a first level expansion, which is exactly what we want to demonstrate for tl like variables. In fact, str, quark and clist variables are particular tl variables. What is surprising is that it is also the case for seq and prop. But prop internals mays change such that V expansion of a prop variable may be an 'f' expansion in the future (https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1047#issuecomment-1036759727)

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS You've discovered that seq, prop and str are macros.

Answer (score 6):

No, they're not the same, even if in some cases they do produce the same result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_jl_test_tl
\int_new:N \l_jl_test_int

\tl_set:Nn \l_jl_test_tl { tokens }
\int_set:Nn \l_jl_test_int { 42 }

\exp_args_generate:n { xV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\exp_args:NxV \use_ii:nn { whatever } \l_jl_test_tl

\par

\exp_args:NxV \use_ii:nn { whatever } \l_jl_test_int

\par

\exp_args:Nxo \use_ii:nn { whatever } { \l_jl_test_tl }

\par

\exp_args:Nxo \use_ii:nn { whatever } { \l_jl_test_int }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you see the problem?

You also see that if some `\exp_args:N...` combination is not available out of the box, you can generate it very simply.

Note that an `o` argument *should* be braced and, to the contrary, a `V` argument shouldn't. The fact that TeX might do the “right” thing anyway is irrelevant.

On the other hand, it is *much* preferable and actually recommended t avoid `\exp_args:N...` when it's more than a one shot case. If you feel the necessity of using `\exp_args:NxV`, then it's quite likely that you want to define the suitable function variant.